# Complex semisimple Lie algebra modules with non-semisimple Cartan action

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\frak{g}$ be a complex semisimple Lie algebra. I would like to know about infinite-dimensional representations $M$ of $\frak{g}$ for which the Cartan $\frak{h} \subseteq \frak{g}$ does **not** act semisimply. Are such representations interesting, and if they are, what are some motivating examples. Also, what can we say about the "number" of such representations? Are they more common "in nature" than representations with a semisimple Cartan action, or are they more rare?

Edit: To clarify, by **the Cartan acting semisimply**  I mean that $M$ has a (Hamel) basis consisting of commoning eigenvectors for the elements of the Cartan.

Comment: What is your definition of semisimple for an operator on an infinite-dimensional space? Is the operator of multiplication by $x$ in $\mathbb C[x,x^{-1}]$ semisimple, for example?

Comment: I would naively suggest that the definition be that $M$ has a (Hamel) basis consisting of commoning eigenvectors for the elements of the Cartan. Is this too restrictive, or non-standard?

Comment: I have no idea what is standard, I just meant that there are several possible meanings, some more restrictive, some less. For example, I encountered (in a paper by Kazhdan and Lusztig) elements $x$ they call regular semisimple which are *topologically nilpotent*, which means that $\operatorname{ad}(x)^n\to\infty$ when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/442916/complex-semisimple-lie-algebra-modules-with-non-semisimple-cartan-action#comment1143167_442916) is less exotic than it might sound, and can be more about the eigenvalues than about any weird eigenspace behaviour; for example, multiplication by $p$ on a 1-dimensional $p$-adic vector space does exactly that.

Comment: Sorry for possible confusion: I should write $\operatorname{ad}(x)^n\to0$ rather than $\to\infty$.

Comment: @LSpice Actually if I am not mistaken that $x$ does not have any proper eigenspaces, hence also no eigenvalues at all. I believe also another $x$, from my first comment, is such.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1143193), by "that $x$" do you mean multiplication by $p$ from [my comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1143186)? That eigenspace is not proper, but it is non-trivial, so I am still accustomed to call $p$ an eigenvalue.  For [KL's elements](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1143167), it is possible that their eigenvalues live in some algebraic extension, but being semisimple means that they are diagonalizable in any algebraic representation over a separably closed field (which is enough to detect top.nilptce.).

Comment: @LSpice No I did not have in mind the $p$-adic case as I know next to nothing about it. What I want to say is that some specialists call regular semisimple elements without any eigenvalues/nontrivial eigenspaces.

Comment: Certainly a lot of natural reps are not weight modules (weight module = module with a semisimple Cartan action). For example, extensions of highest weight modules may not be weight modules. Also, if you take a semisimple real group with no compact Cartan, then the Harish-Chandra modules of the irred reps of such a group may not be weight modules.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1143305), could you say more where you see this usage?  In "[Fixed-point varieties on affine flag manifolds](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02787119)", semisimple elements, including rss, are diagonalizable in any algebraic representation over $\bar F$.  Thus, for KL, an ss element is tn iff its eigenvalues (in any faithful algebraic representation/$\bar F$) are all strictly less than $1$ in absolute value.  (But there's no requirement about eigenvalues in, say, an abstract-gp representation of $G(F)$; maybe that's what you mean.)

Comment: @LSpice Yes, I meant this paper and yes, I meant the adjoint representation. In one of its realizations the element corresponds to the infinite (in all directions) matrix with ones on the diagonal above the main one and zeroes elsewhere. And now I realize this case is in fact not relevant for the question since the corresponding Lie algebra is not finite-dimensional...